# Tag specific filters?

Tags: discussion, tags, filtering

Does Stack Overflow have tag specific filters that can be applied when asking questions? That is, when someone chooses a particular tag, a filter can be applied like the "bad title" filter?

Comment: Is this related to tag blacklisting, to block the tag from being added without removing it from existing questions?

Comment: @Stijn: *"Is this related to tag blacklisting..."* - no, I was thinking of another use. Its the fake information use case that plagues tags like [tag:ssl] and [tag:openssl]. In this use case, folks who ask questions stand up a webserver for the world to beat on. However, they hide the real server name from the handful of people who actively troll the tags and can help them on Stack Overflow. Makes no sense to me, but hey...

Comment: If you don't mean black listing, I don't understand what is being asked here.